# Am I approaching routes in my application wrong?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I've got a couple of actions defined to handle adding/removing an ice cream from a menu.  They look like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddMenuIceCreamMapping(int iceCreamId, int menuId)


[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping(int iceCreamId, int menuId)
```

In order for these actions to not result in a 404 error, I went into the Global.asax.cs file and added the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "AddMenuIceCreamMapping", // Route name
  "IceCream/AddMenuIceCreamMapping/{iceCreamId}/{menuId}", // URLwith parameters
  new
  {
     controller = "IceCream",
     action = "AddMenuIceCreamMapping",
     iceCreamId = UrlParameter.Optional,
     menuId = UrlParameter.Optional
  } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping", // Route name
  "IceCream/RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping/{iceCreamId}/{menuId}", // URLwith parameters
  new
  {
     controller = "IceCream",
     action = "RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping",
     iceCreamId = UrlParameter.Optional,
     menuId = UrlParameter.Optional
  } 
);
```

and those work, meaning I can click an Add or Remove button on my page and add or remove an ice cream/menu mapping.  Great.  But I'm expecting that there will be more situations like this and I can see this routes container having more entries such as these.  And to my novice web programmer eye, it seems a bit clunky and I begin to think that perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.  Am I?  Is there a better way to approach this so that I don't end up doing the "go create some action that takes N parameters and then go add a route" thing.  Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use placeholders in your mappings to deal with this... Instead of what you've got above, you could use this (note that I don't specify a default):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "TwoParameterRoute", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}", // URL with parameters
               );
```

And if you have to add a route that takes three parameters, you extend the idea:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ThreeParameterRoute", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}" // URL with parameters
               );
```

In a controller for the two parameter route, the code would look like this (for a contrived sample):

```
public ActionResult Index(int id1, int id2)
    {
        ViewData["id1"] = id1;
        ViewData["id2"] = id2;

        return View();
    }
```

One final thing to note is that you can change the naming to match a pattern you might have. In the first example, instead of `id1` and `id2` you might have `entityId` and `relatedId` or something similar.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, Rick.  The first one takes care of anything that has a controller, action and two parameters, right?  I guess my follow-up is to ask about not specifying a default.  Is that a (I cringe at this phrase but I'll use it) "best practice" or just a personal preference?

Comment: @itsmatt I've always done it that way for the sake of explicitness and to prevent conflict with another route. If there's no default specified for `TwoParameterRoute` then there isn't a conflict with the default route. That way, there isn't ever ambiguity about the routing decisions -- `IceCream/RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping` will never get confused with `Home/Index`. Make sense?

Comment: @itsmatt Sorry, I just realized I ignored the first part of your comment... Yes, the `TwoParameterRoute` takes care of anything with a controller, an action, and two parameters just like the default route handles anything with a controller, an action and (optionally) a parameter. The default route also specifies defaults in the event that an action isn't provided for a controller or no controller/action is specified at all.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like the most straightforward approach to implement for me.

Answer (score 1):

You know that you can also use querystring parameters even with POST requests? Using just the default route (that comes with new ASP.NET MVC projects), you can reach your actions with `/IceCream/AddMenuIceCreamMapping/?iceCreamId=1&menuId=1` and `/IceCream/RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping/?iceCreamId=1&menuId=1`.

Using querystringparameters also show that this url is a parameterized method call, and not a reference to a resource, as the original URLs would indicate.

Comment: yeah, but just look at it - does it look pretty, SEO friendly, easy understandable?

Comment: @mare: This is a command to the system to add/remove something from a menu. It doesn't need to be pretty, and it certainly doesn't need to be SEO friendly (as you don't want this URL indexed). On the other hand it IS easily understandable, as it clearly tells me what the parameters mean.

Comment: ok, I do agree, I should point out then that it is a matter of personal taste and if you ask me, I don't like it

Answer (score 0):

If your set of CRUD actions will be repeating with every custom Entity that you introduce in your application, then you can have the controller as a parameter too. As it is now, you have controller fixed. Also I would avoid such long action names. I would also avoid spelling `Icecream` as `IceCream`. Just coz of its looks.

Probably you should have a controller `Menu`, which handles Icecreams. It kinda doesn't make sense that Icecream handles its own things because it is a part of something else.

Such as

```
routes.MapRoute( 
  "RemoveIcecreamFromMenu", // Route name 
  "menu/remove-icecream/{iceCreamId}/{menuId}", // URLwith parameters 
  new 
  { 
     controller = "Menu", 
     action = "RemoveIcecream", 
     iceCreamId = UrlParameter.Optional, // i don't think those two should be optional
     menuId = UrlParameter.Optional 
  }  
);
```

But it makes sense for an Icecream controller to handle its own CRUD:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
  "CreateIcecream", // Route name 
  "icecream/create", // URLwith parameters 
  new 
  { 
     controller = "Icecream", 
     action = "Create"
  }  
); 

routes.MapRoute( 
  "DeleteIcecream", // Route name 
  "icecream/delete/{id}", // URLwith parameters 
  new 
  { 
     controller = "Icecream",
     action = "Delete",
     id = @"\d+" // this tells the routing engine only integer are accepted
  }  
);
```

Comment: mare, so in your example, I'd still have an add and a remove for mapping an ice cream to a menu, right?  You've just shown "menu/remove-icecream/{iceCreamId{/{menuId}" but there would be a similar one for add-icecream too, right?

Comment: of course, I left that one out, because it follows the same logic- And yes, of course you would still need both these routes, coz you can't add or remove an icecream from a menu if you don't have them, can you?

Comment: hm...spelling it `Icecream` because of "the looks" ?? Are you aware that ice cream is two words, not one? And should thus when used in class names be Pascal-cased properly as IceCream. And if you're still uncertain about it, take a browse to http://icecream.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something that had descriptive urls and no default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "IceCreamEdit", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/icecream/{iceCreamId}/menu/{menuId}" // URLwith parameters
);
```

Comment: So, does this end up looking like /IceCream/MyAction/icecream/42/menu/6 ?  Essentially, the "icecream" and "menu" parts of the path just provide context for the values 42 and 6?

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way, it makes the route and everything that flows from that too complicated. Routes should be as simple and as short as possible

Comment: @mare - I don't agree. Not all routes need to be as simple and short as possible. Sure, routes that are common can be simple and short, for example a view route could be "i/{iceCreamId}" and be set to a predefined controller and action to show details about a certain type of icecream, but they don't all need to be.

Comment: @Gisli: sure they don't need to be but they certainly can be made to be. All things in life should be as simple as possible, unfortunately people unnecessarily complicate them. Based on my two and a half years of experience with MVC, I 99% sure a route like this will cause issues in the future - most likely hard to debug/identify routing issues when other routes are introduced.